# Where can I find CS problem set resources?

Tags: programming-languages

I am trying to learn to program and I don't just want to learn syntax, but rather learn and practice breaking up and solving problems. Now, I want to know where can I go to get hold of material that ranges in programming problems from beginner to intermediate and hopefully even further so that I can train my problem-solving skills. Any tips or advice on how to train problem-solving skills would be highly appreciated too.

Comment: Programming is offtopic here. Since googline "programming problems" or "programming contest" is bound to give you hundreds of results, I don't think you need to post this question anywhere at all. (Note that effective googling skills are very important in a programmer's life!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/)?

It is more focused on mathematics but still a really nice [set of problems](https://projecteuler.net/archives) which range in the difficulty from easy to tough.

I enjoy it every time and it is a nice approach for diggin into a new programming language, like Haskell.

Comment: Thank you I will check it out and mark your answer, but I just want to leave the question open for more suggestions.

Comment: Will mark in about an hour!

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

i don't know how far along you are in your learning but I found that actually coding is the best way.
try [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/). it is a graphical interface for code that jigsaws together only in ways that are syntactically correct so, as you have asked, you can learn to structure code and create anything you like without learning an actual language. it makes understanding simple coding very easy. Enjoy

Comment: I know C# so I wanted like Questions or material that teaches CS concepts not just code syntax.